# Copy string with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have hundreds of variables with this structure:

```
$bsdatA = $_POST['bsdat_a'];
$bsdatB = $_POST['bsdat_b'];
```

...

The problem is that i have to add isset() function to every of it, like this:

```
$bsdatA = isset($_POST['bsdat_a']) ? $_POST['bsdat_a'] : '';
$bsdatB = isset($_POST['bsdat_b']) ? $_POST['bsdat_b'] : '';
```

...

This is a manual copy and paste on every single line... Can it be done via regular expression? If yes, can someone write me down the exact formula? It would save me lot of time.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what are the possible structures if hundreds are possible?

Comment: check your ide for refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to change the code using an IDE that supports Regex Replaces:

Here's the regex for Eclipse:

Find:

`\$(\w+) = \$_POST\['(\w+)'\]`

Replace:

`$1 = isset(\$_POST['$2']) ? \$_POST['$2'] : '';`

Comment: Thank you. Yes i forgot to tell, that this replace is needed in the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, not a regex, because I don't see how that'd help, but here's a function that can simplify the coding by a lot:

```
<?php
function postvar($index){
   return isset($_POST[$index]) ? $_POST[$index] : '';
}

$bsdatA = postvar('bsdat_a');
```

I'd use `postvar('bsdat_a')` directly, instead of putting the outcome in a variable, by the way, because you risk ending up with a lot of variables you're only going to use once. If you're absolutely sure you want to have `$bsdatA` and `$bsdatB` as local variables, then I would suggest using a loop:

```
<?php
foreach( range('A', 'Z') as $current ) {
   ${'bsdat'.$current} = postvar('bsdat_'.strtolower($current));
}
```

But then, that's just scary :)

**EDIT**: Ah, you're talking about an existing script, and you want to change it to include a lot of isset() calls? Sorry I didn't pick up on that.

You could replace $_POST with an object that implements ArrayAccess. This way, you can also log POST variables that are called, but not used:

```
<?php
class PostVars implements ArrayAccess {
    protected $vars;
    public $log;

    public function __construct($vars) {
        $this->vars = $vars;
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        if(!isset($this->vars[$offset])) {
            $this->log[] = $offset;
        }
        return $this->vars[$offset];

    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->vars[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        // readonly.
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        // readonly.
    }
}

$_POST = array('bsdat_a' => 'bar', 'bsdat_b' => null);

$_POST = new PostVars($_POST);

echo $_POST['bsdat_a'];
echo $_POST['bsdat_b'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\$(\w+)\s+=\s+\$_POST\[\'([^\']+)\'\];/', 
            '$\1 = isset($_POST[\'\2\']) ? $_POST[\'\1\'] : \'\';', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following for POST variables: [import_request_variables('p');](http://php.net/manual/en/function.import-request-variables.php) preferably with a prefix added in the second argument for a little safety.